# cannot install python numpy on kali

Tags: linux, python, kali-linux

I am trying to install python-numpy (for Python 2.7) on my linux VM. The problem I am facing is that when I run

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

I get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-numpy
```

AND when i use .deb to install it,

```
sudo dpkg -i python-numpy_1.16.2-1_amd64.deb
```

I get this error

```
Selecting previously unselected package python-numpy.
(Reading database ... 330820 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack python-numpy_1.16.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-numpy (1:1.16.2-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-numpy:
 python-numpy depends on python (<< 2.8); however:
  Package python is not installed.
 python-numpy depends on python (>= 2.7~); however:
  Package python is not installed.
 python-numpy depends on python:any (<< 2.8).
 python-numpy depends on python:any (>= 2.7~).

dpkg: error processing package python-numpy (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for kali-menu (2021.4.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-numpy
```

But I already have python2.7 installed and the `python` command also points to `python2.7`

```
python    
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar 28 2022, 20:47:09) 
[GCC 11.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088227/package-python-is-not-installed-but-it-is) I was told to install python2.7-dev I did but it didn't work.

Please help me out.

cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# See https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

# Additional line for source packages
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Using Python2.7 because zenmap has a dependency on it and I need it.

Comment: Try this tutorial.  I use Installltion quite a bit for my Kali machine.  https://installlion.com/kali/kali/main/p/python-numpy/install/index.html

Comment: @John I tried `sudo apt-get install python-numpy` and I retried rn to check, it tells me `E: Unable to locate package python-numpy`

Comment: Which repos are enabled for the system? Can you add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question?

Comment: I don't know if it is practical for you, but you might try completely uninstalling python first, restart and then try installing what you need.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Idk why the downvotes honestly. I need this as well to source an sdk. I can't install neither `python-numpy` nor `python-opencv`.

Comment: @M.K I couldn't solve this, it turns out that newer versions of Kali has removed all the programs that were < Python3 dependent as it switched to Python3 itself. And since the program I was trying to run was completely Py2.7 dependent (with no updates coming any time soon), I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this answers your question, but to install a python module you should use `pip install <module>`.
For numpy :

```sh
pip install numpy
```

`sudo` is not required for this, otherwise numpy will be installed as root.

Also, is there a real reason you use pytohn 2.7 and not python3 ? python2.7 should only be used when compatibility doesn't allow you to use newer version (when working on a old application for instance).
To install python3 :

```sh
# Always make sure apt is up to date
sudo apt update

# install python3
sudo apt install python3
```

Don't forget to remove python2.7 before.
Hope that helps you.

Comment: I need to install zenmap, and it has a python2.7 dependency, that's why